# Unable to fetch the merge field in VisualForce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am using a Visualforce email Template. I am unable to fetch merge fields.
Below is the code:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Volunteer still needed for a shift" recipientType="User" 
                                        relatedToType="GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Shift__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Volunteer is still needed for a future shift. 

Please click below to see the shift.
https://cs18.salesforce.com/{!relatedToType.Id}

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

When I try to save it, it gives error like Error:

> Unknown property 'String.Id'

Comment: Have you tried using just `{!relatedTo}`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `{!relatedTo.ID}` instead of `{!relatedToType.Id}`